# Python - do I need to learn about old style classes?

Tags: python, class, types, language-features

I am currently learning Python 2.6.5 and I found out about old style classes and new style classes.

I understand that these classes are still existing only for backward compatibility and that they are removed in Python 3.

So the question is this: **as a newcomer to the language, do I need to learn about the classic classes?**

P.S. I am learning Python 2 because Python 3 is still not fully supported in frameworks and I want to learn some frameworks too. The plan will be to move to Python 3 when frameworks catch up, but until then, do I need to worry about the old style classes?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No.  Don't bother.  Simply inherit all your classes from `object` (or from classes that inherit from `object`) and you will be good to go.  Then when you transition to Python 3 you can forget that bit of syntax.

There's no advantage to using or even learning about old-style classes at this point.

So just make sure all of your class declarations look like this:

```
class foo(object):
    ...
```

(or inherit from something other than `object` which *does* inherit from `object`), and then pretend this is the way that it has always been!

Answer (score 4):

Although I agree with Daniel DiPaolo that you should never need to *use* old-style classes in your code, there will be times when you will need to understand them a little bit.

For example, with old-style classes you can't use `super` to call a parent method - and this can bite you when you try and subclass, for example, the `urllib2.Request` class. If you do this without realising you'll get the cryptic error `super() argument 1 must be type, not classobj`, which can take ages to debug.

(As you can probably tell, I've been there...)